# Edit PATH by adding current directory. To compile a *.c file without by typing a filename without "./"

Tags: c, compilation, directory, csh

I added this line:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

to my `.bash_profile`.

Now I have to make `main.c` compile when I type `zz` (under the same directory in `~/user/filename`)

1. What do I have to write in the `zz` shell script?
2. Did I add the current directory correctly?

Comment: Adding `.` to your PATH is a bad bad idea.

Comment: i know. it's just for this thing to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` determines where executables are searched; it has no influence on where source files are searched. Source files without a directory component are searched in the current directory anyway. What you have to write to compile `main.c` depends on the compiler used, which you didn't specify, but it's usually like `cc main.c`. Also consider using `make` rather than writing a shell script.